# update value of one object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, for-loop, ionic-framework

I am trying to update one value in an array. Basically I want to update the status value of one object in an array. Here is my array

```
[
  {
    "projects": {
      "projectname": "one",
      "dateadded": "16 April 2018, 7:23AM",
      "status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "projects": {
      "projectname": "two",
      "dateadded": "16 April 2018, 7:23AM",
      "status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "projects": {
      "projectname": "three",
      "dateadded": "16 April 2018, 7:32AM",
      "status": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Here is my attempt but it updates everything in array.
Parameter 1 is the name of the project - to see if I am on the correct project

```
archive(){

    var parameter1 = this.navParams.get('param1');

    this.storage.get('projectsStore').then(data => {

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].projects.projectname == parameter1) {
          this.project = [{ "projectname":data[i].projects.projectname, "dateadded":data[i].projects.dateadded, "location":data[i].projects.location, "status":0 }];
        }
      }

    });

    this.storage.set( 'projectsStore', this.project );

}
```

So to clarify this is what I want to achieve. Lets say the user executes the archive function for project three then the array needs to look like this(status is updated for project 3 but not for project 1 and 2)

```
[
  {
    "projects": {
      "projectname": "one",
      "dateadded": "16 April 2018, 7:23AM",
      "status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "projects": {
      "projectname": "two",
      "dateadded": "16 April 2018, 7:23AM",
      "status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "projects": {
      "projectname": "three",
      "dateadded": "16 April 2018, 7:32AM",
      "status": 0
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: my thinking now is that I need to get the existing array and set as new array, then only push updated object to it

Comment: What is `this.project` supposed to refer to?

Comment: this.project is a blank array set globally on the page `project = [];`

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. You want to add one value to that blank array? Probably best if you add some more detail to your question.

Comment: I want to get existing values and populate the array hence my for loop and eg. `data[i].projects.projectname` but also want to update the status parameter in a single object to 0. I need all existing values to be in the array, just need to update the status value in a single object

Comment: I clarified question above

Comment: Why do you have that extra nested object with a single `projects` key in your array?

Comment: I guess its not needed, was where my think was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update the `status` for `projectname` === `parameter1` , you can just

```js
var parameter1 = 'three';

var data = [{
    "projects": {
      "projectname": "one",
      "dateadded": "16 April 2018, 7:23AM",
      "status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "projects": {
      "projectname": "two",
      "dateadded": "16 April 2018, 7:23AM",
      "status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "projects": {
      "projectname": "three",
      "dateadded": "16 April 2018, 7:32AM",
      "status": 1
    }
  }
];

data.forEach(v => {
  //Test if projectname  == parameter1. If it is update status
  if (v.projects.projectname === parameter1) v.projects.status = 0;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: let me try this dynamically

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function updateProject(projectName){
    let toBeUpdated = projects.find(item => item.projects.projectname === projectName);
    toBeUpdated && (toBeUpdated.projects.status = 0);
}
```

Comment: It will update, toBeUpdated will have reference to the same object in an array, so updating 'toBeUpdated' will update the array. Try it

Comment: And also it will not make unnecessary iterations like the accepted answer does.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should modify your JSON schema. Being an array of objects is fine, but keeping "projects" as a key does not seem logical to me. Instead of this, you can have the project name as the key of the JSON object of the project. It should look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "one": {
      "dateadded": "16 April 2018, 7:23AM",
      "status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "two": {
      "dateadded": "16 April 2018, 7:23AM",
      "status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "three": {
      "dateadded": "16 April 2018, 7:32AM",
      "status": 1
    }
  }
]
```

This structure will let you update the status easily for any project. Once you have this structure, you can just update the status of a single project by using this function below:

```
 this.storage.get('projectsStore').then(data => {
   data[parameter1].status = 0;
});
```